# not able to format pendrive after errror while formatting in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I have a 32GB hp pendrive, i tried to format it using slow format process in ubuntu. After some time it showed some error. now it is not readable in any operating system and even i tried to hdparm command to remove the read only attribute. Nothing seems working.
please help

Comment: Does it show up in the *disks* application?

Comment: You can analyze the problem and try some methods to make the drive work again according to this link, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)